# I have 1/2 electricity in my master bedroom, exterior walls have no power

Tags: electrical

I have 3 outlets on exterior walls out. The rest of bedroom has power. Checked breakers, none popped.. Have 2 GFI plugs in bathroom,reset them.. Did notice that I have a 3 way switch on the wall that controls 1 outlet on interior wall.  Turned that on,nothing..
But, it did that before I was told.. Any suggestions???

Comment: Turn the breaker off, and start pulling out receptacles. Look for loose, damaged connections.

Comment: Have you had any work done lately like siding installed? Have you made any changes to anything lately? Did it just start doing this or has it been this way since you moved in?

Comment: Did you actually try to reset the breakers or just did a visual check? On some breakers, the handle doesn't obviously move when tripped. Try turn them off and back on.

Comment: Are you sure the breaker you think controls those outlets is the correct breaker?  One option, have someone with a cell phone go up to the room with a plugin light. One by one, turn off and on each breaker, checking each recepticle every time. This will check ot make sure each breaker is on and check each recepticle.  If you think the bathroom is on the same circuit, have them check those as well.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the breaker, are all the outlets dead now? Start with the last outlet that was working prior to turning off the breaker pull it out.
If the wires are pushed in to the back of the outlet push in and pull out on each one, if the wire pulls loose that outlet may need to be replaced.
If the wires are pigtailed make sure the wire nuts are tight.then go to the first dead outlet. if no problems are found start at the other end(outlets are normally daisy chained and it will be the last good one or first dead one not passing power to the others. Other than recent construction damaging a wire the above check has fixed many dead outlets.